# Javascript - Regex to validate a tridion tcm id

Tags: regex, tridion

Validating a tridion TCM ID using Regex on javascript, looks quiet simple but unfortunately I failed to do this.

I have attempted all the possible ways to validate a tcm id.

Below is the last tried regex:-

```
(tcm:(\d)+-(\d)+(-16|-4|-64))\W
```

Here, `TCM ID` can be `component` or `SG` or `Page`.

Valid tcm id's are

1. tcm:123-5678-4
2. tcm:123-5678-64
3. tcm:123-5678-16
4. tcm:123-5678

Please suggest the best regex to validate a tcm id.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
/^tcm:\d{3}-\d{4}(?:-16|-4|-64)?$/
```

Comment: You might want to remove the exact cardinalities from the regex, since there may be more or fewer digits in each of the numbers. So `/^tcm:\d+-\d+(?:-16|-4|-64)?$/`. You should also consider if you want to match every item type and if so, update the last match group accordingly. In the most generic case it can be just `/^tcm:\d+-\d+(?:-\d+)?$/`. Finally: keep in mind that a TCM URI **can** also refer to a specific version and thus end with `-v123`. so that would lead to `/^tcm:\d+-\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:-v\d+)?$/`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Thanks frank. I will follow your guidelines.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: +1 for your nice comment. I suggest, you should post your comment as the answer. It will help to others..

Answer (score 9):

The regex xdazz provided is great for matching the examples you gave. But for more generic handling you might want to:

1. remove the exact cardinalities from, since there may be more or fewer digits in each of the numbers. So `/^tcm:\d+-\d+(?:-16|-4|-64)?$/`
2. consider if you want to match every item type and if so, update the last match group accordingly. In the most generic case it can be just `/^tcm:\d+-\d+(?:-\d+)?$/`
3. keep in mind that a TCM URI can also refer to a specific version and thus end with -v123. so that would lead to `/^tcm:\d+-\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:-v\d+)?$/`

Of course that brings you pretty close to Nuno's answer, which has the added advantage that the match groups have readable names.

Comment: Thanks for posting as answer. +1 for generic answer.

Answer (score 5):

I used this in c# to validate a Tcm Uri (and I believe this is also how `TcmUri.IsValid()` is doing it)

```cs
"^tcm:(?<pubId>[0-9]+)-(?<itemId>[0-9]+)(-(?<itemType>[0-9]+))?(-v(?<version>[0-9]+))?$"
```

If you want to validate that it is a page or a component, then itemType should be empty, 16 or 64.

Comment: Thanks Nuno for providing it in C#. It helps a lot. +1 for the answer.